# ERROR in ./src/components/navbar/HomeNav.js Module build failed - Webpack error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs, jsx

I have a react project that was created by CRA. Now i installed webpack because i wanted to add Jquery into config. Now I am getting this error after initializing webpack:

Could someone help me?

[cli image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4UMvC.png)

**Webpack.config.js**

```
    const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const InterpolateHtmlPlugin = require('interpolate-html-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: "./src/index.js",
    output: {
      path: __dirname + "/dist",
      filename: "./bundle.js",
    },
    mode: 'development',
    devServer: {
      port: 3000,
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
            test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
            exclude: /(node_modules)/,
            use: {
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                options: {
                    presets: ['@babel/preset-env','@babel/react'],
                    plugins: ['@babel/proposal-class-properties', '@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread', '@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import']
                }
            }
        },
        { test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/, loader: 'url-loader' },
        {
            test: /\.css$/i,
            use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
        }
      ],
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx']
    },
    plugins: [
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: "./dist/index.html",
        filename: './index.html',
        favicon: './dist/favicon.ico'
      }),
      new InterpolateHtmlPlugin({
        PUBLIC_URL: 'static' // can modify `static` to another name or get it from `process`
      })  
    ],
  };
```

**.babelrc**

```
  {
    "presets": [
        "@babel/preset-env",
        "@babel/preset-react"
    ]
}
```

please help

Comment: Are you trying to destructure NavItem?

Comment: Provide HomeNav.js file code as well.

Comment: @darkwex it looks like you have a type declaration on your component but you are not using Typescript. Try to remove `:NavItem` and see if it fixes the problem.

Comment: `:NavItem` is used on TypeScript, if you are using js then remove it

Comment: I got those codes from chakra ui templates.